# copy+paste between linux desktop and vmware player?

Tags: vmware, copy-paste

How can I copy+paste text between my linux desktop (GNOME Ubuntu 11.04) and the open vmplayer window running an ubuntu 64bit server terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the VMWare Tools package in the guest OS, then copy and paste should work seamlessly between host and guest.